# jquery detect hash in url trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, click

I have looked at a lot of examples on SO but can't seems to see what the issue is with my code:

I have urls that have hash tags / jump to id values appended to them. I want to check if the url has a hash tag and use that value as a click event like i would do on the page when clicking a button.

example url:
http://domain.com/#help-video-modal-tags

jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    if ( window.location.hash ) {

        function showVideo() {
            alert('in the function');
        }

        jQuery(window.location.hash).click(showVideo);

}
});
```

current click event triggers function

```
showVideo();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `current click event triggers function`?

Comment: Do you actually want to TRIGGER a click or do you just want to add a click event listener? Your code does the latter. So if you click on the element with the same id as the hash, it should work.

Comment: the page has a click event that is also on a <a> link that will run the showVideo() function. I basically want to run that same action of clicking the <a> link but when the page loads by checking the hash value in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    if ( window.location.hash ) {

        function showVideo(hash) {
            alert('in the function, hash -> ' + hash);
        }

        jQuery(document).click(showVideo(window.location.hash));

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly to trigger an event of certain element is:

```
$('elem').trigger('click');
```

So in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if ( window.location.hash ) {   
        $(window.location.hash).trigger('click');//and trigger the event when needed
   }
});

function showVideo() {
  alert('do something when click is trigger');
}

$('elem').click(showVideo); //assign the event function normally
```